# Moving SQL 2008 from 2003 OS to virtual 2012 OS

Tags: sql-server, migration

If we wanted to move SQL 2008 from a 2003 OS to a virtual 2012 OS (using VM Ware), does anyone know if there are any licensing or technical problems that would get in the way?

All the instructions I've seen on moving SQL server from one machine to another assume the new machine has the same OS. I realize that there are licences have more cores and fail over capability, but for now we are fine with a simple installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're moving from the *same* version of SQL Server across different versions on Windows Server, you should be fine. Just dump the databases and restore them on the new box, migrate/recreate user permissions, and you're done.

Comment: @David SQL Server doesn't care what OS it's on as long as it's supported by Microsoft. SQL Server 2008 doesn't really behave any differently based on which Windows OS it's running on top of.